# Unable to set up laravel homestead

Tags: homestead

i am trying to set up laravel homestead on windows 10 and i am unable to navigate into my projects folder.This is my Homestead.yaml `---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
- map: C:/LaravelHome
to: /home/vagrant/LaravelHome

sites:
- map: homestead1.test
to: /home/vagrant/LaravelHome/homestead1/public

databases:
- homestead

features:
- mysql: true
- mariadb: false
- postgresql: false
- ohmyzsh: false
- webdriver: false

`so everytime i try to cd into LaravelHome so as to set up a project,i get this feedback even though i have the directory on my C drive`vagrant@vagrant:~$ pwd
/home/vagrant
vagrant@vagrant:~$ cd LaravelHome
-bash: cd: LaravelHome: No such file or directory
vagrant@vagrant:~$
` What could i be doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

it should be...

```
folders:
    - map: C:\LaravelHome
      to: /home/vagrant/code
```

the slash is in wrong direction...

You may refer to my step-by-step guide
https://medium.com/@dogcomp/ec996f9a2cb6